# Remove anything after last instance of character in Excel

Tags: excel, parsing

I have 1 column:

```
           A      
new|1234|dke      
new|123|jkle     
   kjd|endk|
    jlfdjfla
```

How do I create a new column where I only keep everything to the left of the last `|`?

Expected Output:

```
           A      
   new|1234|      
    new|123|     
   kjd|endk| 
    jlfdjfla
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1, FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A1, "|", CHAR(1), LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "|", ""))))-1),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: beat me by 2 seconds

Comment: This is great thank you! Is there a way to keep that last `|` instead of removing it? Or is there a quick and dirty way to attaching `|` to the end of it based on this?

Comment: actually, I'll just use concatenate for the final part. Thank you!

Comment: @nak5120 - Yeah, just take out that `-1` in the formula, at this part `..."|", ""))))-1),A1)`